# parse method in DocumentBuilder is returning an error

Tags: java, swing, javax.xml

I am trying to use the `parse` method that takes an `InputSource` to parse a `DocumentBuilder` instance.

The error is:

> The method parse(InputStream) in the type DocumentBuilder is not
>   applicable for the arguments (InputSource)

This is the code:

```
public static Document loadXMLFromString(String xml) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilder factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = factory.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));   
}
```

It is asking me to change to `InputStream`.. Checked the documentation and one of the parse methods in `DocumentBuilder` takes an `InputSource`. What is the problem?

Comment: Are you importing org.xml.sax.ImportSource or another class?

Comment: my relevant imports                                                                               import javax.swing.text.Document; 
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import jdk.internal.org.xml.sax.InputSource;   @Kagemusha

Comment: You got your imports wrong. Clement Amarnath's answer will fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem may be due to a bad import of class `InputSource`.
Please `org.xml.sax.InputSource` is imported .

`DocumentBuilder` accept `org.xml.sax.InputSource` but not `jdk.internal.org.xml.sax.InputSource`

Answer (score 1):

Use this import `import org.xml.sax.InputSource;` instead of this `import jdk.internal.org.xml.sax.InputSource;` after doing this step then you will face error on Document modify that import from `import javax.swing.text.Document;` to `import org.w3c.dom.Document;`