# Trying to convert xml string into a document object, getting error through IDE

Tags: java, xml

I have been trying to convert an xml string into a document so I can later add a node, I have found the same solution in 5 different places however my IDE is giving me an error. The error reads as "the method parse(inputstream)in type DocumentBuilder is not applicable for the arguments(inputSource)."

I have tried the exact code multiple times including choosing the right method output, but I keep getting the same error.

```
private static Document converStringToDocument(String xml) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
        return document;
    }
```

I want this to return a document so I can add a node.

Comment: what is your `Java` version?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38137291/parse-method-in-documentbuilder-is-returning-an-error?rq=1